# Integer eigenvalues in Matlab

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I am trying to write a Matlab program which decides if a given (integer) matrix A has integer eigenvalues and if this is the case calculates the eigenvalues and their multiplicities. Any ideas how to get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A first step is to be able to get the characteristic polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients. For this, use the [Faddeev-Leverrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm).

Indeed, with this algorithm, you can keep integer values all the way long because it uses traces of powers of your matrix $A$.

Of course, the size of $A$ shouldn't be too large ; otherwise, Matlab  will switch to "floating point" numbers at a certain step...

Now, for the roots. As roots are usually within a rather narrow range, a simple testing for example with integers between $−1000 \le n \le 1000$ whether $P(n)=0$ or not, will do the job... in at most 1 millisecond. The question of roots with absolute value $>1000$ can be treated in a separate way.

For multiple roots, test if $P(n)=0$ and $P'(n)=0$ for a double root ; if moreover $P(n)=P'(n)=P''(n)=0$, it is triple root, etc.

A different type of action using the `"eig"` function provides you the floating point values of eignevalues. If you are **allowed to** use this function, you can take their rounded value (to the next integer) and test whether these rounded values  are (exact!) roots of the characteristic polynomial.